# Grammar of 'dare' in this example

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs, semi-modals

What is the grammar of the verb 'dare' in the following example?

> The pizza was nice but, *dare* I say it, the salad was awful.

Is it some type of imperative?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Dare* (like *need*) is a semi-modal verb, which means that in certain environments (see [**Negative Polarity**](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf)), of which *Yes/No* Questions are one, *dare* may be used as a modal auxiliary verb.

If you substitute any other modal for *dare* in the sentence, you'll see what I mean:

- *The pizza was nice but, **may** I say it, the salad was awful.*
- *The pizza was nice but, **can** I say it, the salad was awful.*
- *The pizza was nice but, **might** I say it, the salad was awful.*

These aren't all idioms like *dare I say*, and of course they don't mean the same, but they illustrate how modals work in questions. The only unusual thing is using *dare* as a modal verb here.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but I'd just add that I tend to punctuate such sentences as 'The pizza was nice but - dare I say it? - the salad was awful.'

Comment: Such [punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf) is intended to indicate the intonation that holds the ideas together in speech, which is **widely** variable, so any punctuation that works for the author may well work for the reader. There isn't any right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The statement "I dare (to) say it" one would expect to become a question as "Do I dare say it?" (and I would not object to that) ... But--as noted by John Lawler--"dare" is sometimes an auxiliary verb, and then it doesn't need the "do" so we can have "Dare I say it?".  The other examples, "can, might" are auxiliary verbs only, so they will always act like this, and we CANNOT make questions like "*Do I can say it?" or "*Do I might say it?"